# Were the amount of the stack space, used in a recursion, zero if we would pass the vars by reference?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, callstack

Let we have the following function that taking a pointer to the root and return `true` on finding the element and `false` otherwise

```
/**
* A method to test if an item is in a subtree.
* x is item to search for.
* ptr is the node that roots the subtree.
*/
template<typename T>
bool contains( const T & x, Node *t ) const
{
    if( ! ptr ) return false;
    else if( x < ptr->data ) return contains( x, ptr->left );
    else if( ptr->data < x ) return contains( x, ptr->right );
    else return true; // Match
}
```

The expected call stack space used is expected to be `O(log(N))` due to copying of pointers every call.

Now if we replace the previous code by the following one, will the space use be zero or what??

```
template<typename T>
bool contains( const T & x, Node* & ptr ) const
{
    if( !ptr ) return false;
    else if( x < ptr->data ) return contains( x, ptr->left );
    else if( ptr->data < x ) return contains( x, ptr->right );
    else return true; // Match
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if reference parameters didn't take up stack space *at all* (and they can take up said space), any implementation of those function calls that doesn't perform tail recursion optimization will have at least one thing on the stack: a pointer to where to return to. Indeed, not having a return address is basically what a tail call is.

Basically, there's nothing you can do to *guarantee* tail calls in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Can the provided function be optimized using a recursion algorithm (not by while loop).